# how can i send this to wp_head - escape problem

Tags: javascript, wp-head, escaping

how can escape this char ---->  ;

**i ask becuse i want to use this to send some javascript
to the head using wp_head**

this is want i want to attach to wp_head:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_lighbox_portfolio');

function load_lighbox_portfolio() {
    echo '<!--===STR=========== LIGHTBOX =================-->'. "\n";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo('template_url') .'/jquery-lightbox/js/jquery.js"></script>' . "\n";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. get_bloginfo('template_url') .'/jquery-lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>' . "\n";
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'. get_bloginfo('template_url') .'/jquery-lightbox/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />' . "\n";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
    echo '$(function() {' . "\n";
    echo '$('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class' . "\n";
    echo '});' . "\n";
    echo '</script>' . "\n";
    echo '<!--===END=========== LIGHTBOX =================-->'. "\n";   
}
```

Everything works great.. only trouble is that  --->  ; symbole...
i looked for a replacement HTML char but couldnt find one..

Help would be apreaciated :)

Comment: If anyone Dropes by and know how to mark "solved" i would love to know how..

Comment: Answer your own question, and mark it as answered.

Comment: Ok - was afraid that might be rude  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** SOLVED ***
sorry for the bother. my problem wasnt this char at all --> ;
but this line which i missed:

```
echo '$('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class' . "\n";
```

Sometimes sterring at code i miss such stuff.. sorry = thanks for anyone who watched.